# Unable to run/debug c/c++ files on vs code due to empty configurations list in workspace.json file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am unable to run/debug my c++ file on vscode. Everytime I try to do so, a window pops up with this message: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'uri').
[Pop up window that opens on running/debugging code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QMhL.png)

Upon launching the workspace.json file, I get to see this:
[workspace.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtTcb.png)

I guess my configurations list is empty and that is what is causing this issue.
Can someone help me with how to fix this ?

I tried searching for the solution on google but could not find any useful informations as such.

Comment: The message mentions `launch.json`, not `workspace.json`. What does your `launch.json` look like? Have you read [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), which includes examples of `launch.json`?

Comment: And please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your question. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: vscode really isn't beginner friendly for c++, you'll find visual studio much easier to use